# Using and accessing Webresource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webresource

I know this has been asked before. Yes, i did my research but it doesn't seem to be working for me so i hope you experts can help me out :)

Here's what my Project looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPZJ.png

Yes, the Build Action is Embedded Resource. I also added this in the AssemblyInfo

```
Assembly: WebResource("WFL.WebResource.EXT.XXX.png", "image/png")
```

So now, in the default.aspx i say

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        Dim strReturn As String = cs.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "WFL.WebResource.EXT.XXX.png")
        Dim strReturn2 As String = cs.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(_Default), "WFL.WebResource.EXT.XXX.png")

        Image1.ImageUrl = "http://localhost" + strReturn
        Image2.ImageUrl = "http://localhost" + strReturn2

        Response.Write("http://localhost" + strReturn)
        Response.Write("http://localhost" + strReturn2)

    End Sub
```

But when accessing the returned URL, i get **The resource cannot be found.**
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This being VB and not C#, you don't need the .EXT portion in WFL.WebResource.Ext.XXX.png. That is something C# needs (to specify folder paths), but VB doesn't. You just want your namespace then resource. Try WFL.WebResource.XXX.png and see if that works.